# Wildcards (*) in XPath?

Tags: xml, xpath

I am trying to find an element from XML string based on an attribute and I have two situations:

```
//person[contains("name", "aa bb cc")]//phone
```

or

```
//person[contains("name", "aa cc")]//phone
```

I want to find both of these elements, is it possible to use wildcards for this case? I tried:

```
//person[contains("name", "aa*cc")]//phone
```

this doesn't work. Any suggestions?

The XML has this shape, and I want to get all the phone numbers:

```xml
<people>
  <person>
    <phone>315255414</phone>
    <name>aa cc</name>
  </person>

  <person>
    <phone>523525</phone>
    <name>aa bb cc</name>
  </person>
</people>
```

Comment: Please edit your question and show the xml and the expected output based on that xml.

Comment: In your sample xml, both `<name>` elements contain both `aa` AND `cc` -  selecting one of these two strings will select both elements. So are you really concerned about a situation where one `<name>` element contains only `aa`  while the other contains only `cc` and you want to select both but NOT a `<name>` element which contains neither?

Comment: I guess selecting elements that just start with "aa" could work in this case, but for safety it's better to use both conditions

Comment: Sure - for your sample xml, starting with (or containing) `aa` would get both elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you updated the question I would suggest the following XPath expression to find the phone numbers:

```
//person[./*[starts-with(@name,'ab') and ends-with(@name, 'cc')]]/phone
```

In case `name` or `phone` can be a non-direct children of `person` the expression could be changed to the following:

```
//person[.//*[starts-with(@name,'ab') and ends-with(@name, 'cc')]]//phone
```

Answer (score 1):

[Glob pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)) wildcards (where `*` matches any characters), are not supported in XPath, but starting with XPath 2.0, full [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) (where `.*` matches zero or more characters) are supported.

### XPath 2.0

This XPath,

```
//person[matches(name, '^aa.*cc$')]/phone
```

uses XPath 2.0's regular expression facilities to select the `phone` elements of those `person` elements whose `name` child element's string value starts with `aa` and ends with `cc`.

### XPath 1.0

This XPath,

```
//person[starts-with(name, 'aa')][ends-with(name, 'cc')]/phone
```

does the same but only requires XPath 1.0.